# pagebreak, newpage don't work with textblock, textpos

Tags: page-breaking, textpos

I use `textpost`, `textblock` to put two `tcbpost` in one page: [2 tcbposter in one page and set absolute position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514600/2-tcbposter-in-one-page-and-set-absolute-position)

But `\pagebreak`, `\newpage` don't work when I insert another `posterbox` (BOX C).

Please help; don't remove `textblock`.

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute%,showboxes
]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{6}(1,2)
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt},
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=6cm,
  },
  ]
  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  width=5cm, height= 10cm
  ]{ }{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{6}(7,5)
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt},
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=6cm,
  },
  ]
  \posterbox[
  colframe = blue,
  width=5cm, height= 10cm
  ]{ }{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{textblock}
%%%BOX C
    \clearpage
\pagebreak
\newpage

\begin{textblock}{6}(2,5)
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt},
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=6cm,
  },
  ]
  \posterbox[
  colframe = yellow,
  width=5cm, height= 10cm
  ]{ }{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `\newpage` when there is already content on the page, but `\textblock` does not add content to the page (it rather puts something on top of the page). To cure this, add something invisible like `~` before the `\newpage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute%,showboxes
]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{6}(1,2)
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt},
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=6cm,
  },
  ]
  \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  width=5cm, height= 10cm
  ]{ }{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}

\end{tcbposter}

\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{6}(7,5)
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt},
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=6cm,
  },
  ]
  \posterbox[
  colframe = blue,
  width=5cm, height= 10cm
  ]{ }{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{textblock}

~\newpage

\begin{textblock}{6}(2,5)
\begin{tcbposter}[
coverage = {left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt},
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=2,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=6cm,
  },
  ]
  \posterbox[
  colframe = yellow,
  width=5cm, height= 10cm
  ]{ }{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]